# Как посчитать количество нужных букв в строке, с помощью анонимной функции python?

Tags: python

Допустим будет строка: '`Аааа Аааа, ну и ещё Ааааа`'. Нужно вывести `True`, если количество букв `А` НЕ меньше 5, иначе `False`. Причём, без учёте регистра. Пример: `print(anonim_function('Ааааа аа, и ещё ааа'))`, должна вернуть `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = lambda x: True if x.lower().count("a") > 5 else False
```

Comment: Можно записать компактнее - `x = lambda x: x.lower().count("a") > 5`